# Like Box - Blogger Error

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, blogger, facebook-likebox

I'm tring to put facebook Like Box to my blog but after I put Javascript SDK (right after opening  body it show me error
**

> The reference to entity "appId" must end with the ';' delimiter.

**
and I cant fix it ... :(
What I need to do/edit ???

Comment: What shows you the error? is that an error from Facebook's API?

Comment: Yes everything is working perfect(other code) but after I put this code(facebook like box javascript SDK) and press "save" blogger show me this error ...

Comment: So the error is from blogger's side - have you checked their help, or googled to see if this is a common problem? doesn't sound like a problem with Facebook's API

Comment: First of all I want to thank you @Igy for comments.I fixed problems and for all those who have also this problem put Javascript SDK code in 
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
...script here ...
/* ]]> */
</script>
Hope it will help ...
- Adnan

Comment: Just writing the & as `&amp;` should have worked just as well, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: fbml=1 appId where I just deleted & and put the closing script right after Load the SDK line.  I checked it with the debugger and now there are no errors.

I'm not asking for other permissions, just the "like my page."

{edit. had to change to closing script as the brackets and script didn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Change the &appId to &appId ant it will work.